# Bootstrap Validator not working on submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have managed to get the Bootstrap Validator to work as you type. It highlights the boxes in green and red for success and errors while also showing icons. However, once you click the submit button there is no validation happening. The page seems to reload but nothing happens. Eventually, I want this to send the form information to me in an email but I want to get the validation working first and then I'll try to figure that out. Thanks!

HTML form (the final will be much more complicated than this but this is a starting point.)

```
<form id="adopt-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">  
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Street Address</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Your Street Address" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']); ?>">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                 <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
             </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#adopt-form').bootstrapValidator({
            live:'enabled',
            submitButtons: 'button[id="submit"]',
            message:"This value is not valid.",
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
            fields: {
                name: {
                    autoFocus: true,
                    //message: "Name is required.",
                    validators : {
                        stringLength:{
                            min:4,
                        },
                        notEmpty:{
                            //message : "Please provide a name."
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    //message: "Email address is required.",
                    validators : {
                        emailAddress: {
                            //message: "Please enter a valid email address."
                        },
                        notEmpty:{
                            //message : "Please provide an email address."
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        })
    });//document ready
```